# Is there URL filter like protocol in TCP/IP stack?

Tags: router, url, tcpip

I find many type routers have their self-existent URL filter settings.

Tenda:

[image]

Nexxt:

[image]

So, is there a URL filter protocol in TCP/IP stack?

and if is, is there any software for controlling every type's router?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

THis is not part of the base TCP/IP stack and this can't be configured in a router-independent way. Instead, this is a filtering proxy or application level firewall on the router and completely vendor-dependent.

(Note: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TR-069 exists and might or might not have some capabilities to configure such functions, but this would be conceptually no different then e.g. Ansible for server configuration).

Comment: There has a question,  can we develop a  `application level firewall on the router`, then every type router can install it as application, so they can filter URLs?

Answer (score 2):

No. URL filtering happens in Layer 7 so it is completely dependent on each device's implementation.

With the vast majority of the web moving to HTTPS URL filtering becomes much more difficult and I don't expect cheap/entry level devices to be able to do it.